# Keypad mobile text want to add through buttons in edittext in android

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, android-keypad

I am working on an application in which had design one keypad mobile in which added one text and 12 buttons 1,2,3..so on.  want to add text like on pressing 2 getting 2, A, B, C so should enter like a text message. stuck on this could anyone please help me out? thank you if anyone helps.

[image: Keypad mobile design]

I had declared one int counter = 0; above and on the button, I am using the below code.

```
`
String[] input = {"2","A", "B", "C"};
            if(counter < input.length){
                value = value+(input[counter]);
                //value=value+""+d;
                String e =""+editText.getText().toString();
                editText.setText(value);
                counter++;
            }else {
                counter = 0;
            }
```

`

Comment: you should include at least what code have you tried

Comment: thanks for comment i had added code but it happens when i click button 4 times i get C but that is not adding in edittext onebyone